# Help on proving that $\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am currently studying Real Analysis by Royden. In one of the proof of an important theorem on measurable functions, it was stated that:

> $\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}$.

But the book did not show that indeed the statement is TRUE. In showing that the statement is TRUE, one must use double set inclusion. Here is what I have done.

Let $z\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}$. Then there is an index $n$ such that $z\in \{x:f(x)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}$. That is, for that $n$ we have $f(z)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}$. But $f(z)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}$ means that $f(z)>\alpha$. Thus $z\in \{x:f(x)>\alpha\}$.

> Is this correct? Also, how do we show the reverse inclusion? Lastly if $\alpha<\beta<\alpha +\frac{1}{n}$, is it true that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)\geq \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)> \beta\}$?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. As for your last question, $\beta$ is fixed so the latter union is just $\{f > \beta \}$ which in general will not coincide with $\{f > \alpha\}$.

Regarding the proof in the other direction: suppose that $x \in \{f > \alpha\}$, that is, $f(x) > \alpha$. In paticular, $0 < f(x) - \alpha$ and so by archimedianity, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < f(x) - \alpha$, which is equivalent as saying $\alpha + \frac{1}{n} < f(x)$, i.e. $x \in \{f > \alpha + \frac{1}{n}\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{f > \alpha + \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: Thanks @GuidoA. for your answer. I fully understand now the reverse inclusion. Can  you help me in understanding the equality in my last question by providing sketch of the proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You last equality is not always true: we have just proved that the left hand side is $\{f > \alpha\}$. The right hand side is a union of the _same_ set, and in general, $\{f > \alpha\} \neq \{f > \beta\}$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.